# What hood fits a Canon 70-300mm telephoto USM IS lens?

Tags: canon, lens-hood

I have a Canon 70-300mm lens on my 1200D. I am at college and have been told we need to get a hood for my camera. I do wildlife photography, and I have no idea what type of hood would be best. Can someone advise please?

Answer (score 1):

If your lens is the **Canon EF 70-300mm f/4-5.6 IS USM**, the official lens hood is specified as **ET-65B** on the [Canon website](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/EF_Lenses/Telephoto_Zoom/EF_70-300mm_f4-5.6_IS_USM/).

If you search "ET-65B hood" on Google or eBay et al, you'll get lots of options to purchase an official Canon one or a third-party imitation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a really tight budget, you can download and print a [pattern](http://www.lenshoods.co.uk/hoods/Canon-EF-70-300mm-f-4-5.6-IS-USM.php) to make a hood for your lens out of stiff paper or cardboard.

This [site](http://www.lenshoods.co.uk/) has patterns for many popular lenses.

Answer (score 0):

Just check Canon's website for the appropriate hood for that lens.  Then you can check any camera store or ebay for the genuine article or a cheaper third party knock off.